# creating Dynamic controls in html with different names

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I am creating radiobuttons in HTML .I am getting data from SQL Database.I am creating an attendence form in which there will be **`student name,Present Radio button ,Absent Radio button.`**
I put the Present and Absent Radio button in a single Group,(so that only one could be clicked.The problem is that I can't create more than one radio group..My code is

```
<html>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $i;?></td> // Serial Number
<td> <label><?php echo $att['std_name'];?></label></td> //student name
<td><input type="radio" name="std_r[]" id="std_r[]"></td> // for present
<td><input type="radio" name="std_r[]" id="std_c[]"></td> // for absent
<td><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $att['rollnum'];?>" > </td> //hidden field that will take roll number of student on next page

</tr>
</html>
<?php
```

I want that for each student there should be seperate group of radio buttons.thats why i want to create buttons with different name.
Anyone who can help me with this
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are asking is there are several students in the same page and each student with his own present/absent option.

You should do something like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="test[1]" value="present" />
<input type="radio" name="test[1]" value="absent" />

<input type="radio" name="test[2]" value="present" />
<input type="radio" name="test[2]" value="absent" />

<input type="radio" name="test[3]" value="present" />
<input type="radio" name="test[3]" value="absent" />
```

You may also specific the student_id as index, this will be easier for you do handle in PHP:

```
<input type="radio" name="test[33888]" value="present" />
<input type="radio" name="test[33888]" value="absent" />

<input type="radio" name="test[90909]" value="present" />
<input type="radio" name="test[90909]" value="absent" />
```

Comment: Very Rite JeffChan,i just solve this we can do this by using a php variable inside the array.